# Using the following jQuery script/ PHP to send attachments from a web page...

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a site **[here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/documents-old.html)**.

The way this page works is great. I can fill out all the fields, and attach a document and hit send and the email goes.

There's a JSFiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/vehy4/)**.

```
                    <td style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Forms <br />you <br />want to <br />attach:</td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <input name="fileAttach[]" type="file" class="multi"><br><br>
                        </td>
```

However, I've set up another page **[here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/documents-new.html)**. This is what I really want.

But, behind each checkbox, I want there to be pre-defined document. An attachment of sorts.

**The logic would work like this...**

1. 'To' box and 'Subject' are filled out.
2. The necessary check boxes are checked.
3. Hit 'Send' and the email goes off.

There's a JSFiddle for this one **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/228cU/)**.

**Here's some code from that one...**

```
</div><!-- Close Form Header -->
    <div class="form-column"><!-- Column -->
    <div class="form-label">Financial Aid Forms</div><!-- Label -->
        <div class="form-content"><!-- Content -->
            <ul>
                <li><input name="fileAttach[]"  type="checkbox" class="multi">Finance Form 1</li><br />
            </ul>
       </div>
```

I can't figure out how to configure the documents behind the check boxes. I simply want the documents to be pulled from the server.

I'm not sure how to include a PHP file in a JSFiddle, so I'm posting the part that relates to the attachment here.

```
<?
$strTo = $_POST["txtTo"];
$strSubject = $_POST["txtSubject"];
$strMessage = nl2br($_POST["txtDescription"]);

//*** Uniq id Session ***//
$strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$strHeader = "";
$strHeader .= "From: ".$_POST["South University"]."<".$_POST["txtFormEmail"].">\nReply-To: ".$_POST["txtFormEmail"]."";

$strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";

//*** Attachment ***//
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"]);$i++)
{
if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"][$i] != "")
{
$strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"][$i];
$strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"][$i])));
$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
}
}

$flgSend = @mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader); // @ = No Show Error //

if($flgSend)
{
echo "Mail send completed.";
}
else
{
echo "Cannot send mail.";
}
?>
```

Or if there's an easier way to do this, please let me know. I still want to maintain the same functionality described above.